# Export Inserts from select query when multiple tables(join) separated by tables

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE A

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 |

TABLE B

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B1 |
| 1 | B2 |

```
Select *
from table_A inner join
     Table_B
     on Table_A.id=Table_B.id_table_a
where Table_A.id=x
```

Currently I have a query(result exported) that shows all data together in the same query like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A ('id','data','id_table_a','data') VALUES ('1','A1','1','B1'),('1','A1','1','B2')

Desired QUERY

INSERT INTO Table_A ('id','data') values ('1','A1');
INSERT INTO Table_B ('id_table_a','data') values ('1','B1');
INSERT INTO Table_B ('id_table_a','data') values ('1','B2');
```

ANOTHER EXAMPLE:

> 

I will try to exemplify: using vehicles

About a particular vehicle, I need to retrieve all the related information that is distributed in other tables

> Blockquote

```
Select * from vehicles v
inner join brands b on b.id = vehicles.id_brand
inner join travels t on t.id_vehicles = v.id
inner join tours r on r.id_travels = travels.id
where vehicles.id = 123

Then with the result of that query, surely you will have several routes for each trip, a single brand and a single vehicle.
```

I want to export this result, as multiple INSERTs, each one being independent of the other or it could be grouped by table

> Blockquote

vehicles:

```
INSERT vehicles (id, id_brand, color, engine ...) Values ​​(123,3, red, indenor);
```

brands:

```
INSERT brands (id, description, status) Values ​​(3, IKA, 100);
```

Vehicles:

```
INSERT travels (id, id_vehicles, status) Values ​​(3,123,100);
INSERT travels (id, id_vehicles, status) Values ​​(11,123,100);
```

tours travel id = 3:

```
INSERT tours (id, id_travel, status) Values ​​(9,3,100);
INSERT tours (id, id_travel, status) Values ​​(11,3,100);
```

tours travel id = 11:

```
INSERT tours (id, id_travel, status) Values ​​(44,11,100);
INSERT tours (id, id_travel, status) Values ​​(61,11,100);
```

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have added another example to try to clarify it

Answer (score 0):

foe get merged resul by rows instead by columns
you could use an union all

```
select id, data 
from tablea

union all 

select id, data 
from tableb
```

eventually prefix by tablename

```
 select 'tablea', id, data 
 from tablea

 union all 

 select'tableb',  id, data 
 from tableb
```